# Given that $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+{a_{n}}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such   that

> $$a_1=1\;\ \text{&}\;\ a_{n+1}=a_n+{a_{n}}^2 \;\;\forall\;\ n\geq 1$$
>   and i have to find what is 
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$$

I have no idea how to think about this ,whenever i try to suppose an example that example does't satisfies the given condition 
please help

Comment: Do you mean $n \to \infty$?

Comment: yes soory i will edit it

Comment: Compute the first 5 values. Can you see that they are (strictly) increasing? Can you prove it? Does that lead to a hypothesis about $a_n$?

Comment: i made i mistake while calculation ,but now i got it thank you

Comment: [Avoid “no clue” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969) – there is always *something* that you can do to approach a problem.

Comment: @MartinR next time i will keep this in mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show by induction that $a_n \ge n$ for all $n$, hence $ 0< \frac{1}{a_n} \le \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: got it,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Trying a few terms 
$$1,2,6,42,1806,3263442,10650056950806\cdots$$

shows you extremely fast growth. This is mostly due to the square.

You can obtain a lower bound by noting that

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_n^2>a_n^2$$ and by induction, the solution of the recurrence

$$a_{n+1}=a_n^2$$ with $a_2=2$, is

$$a_n=2^{2^{n-2}}.$$

---

Note that we have a tighter approximation with

$$a_{n+1}+\frac12=\left(a_n+\frac12\right)^2+\frac14>\left(a_n+\frac12\right)^2$$

leading to

$$a_n=\left(\frac52\right)^{2^{n-2}}-\frac12.$$

Anyway, this is completely unimportant to solve the question, and the approximation given by Fred is more than sufficient !

Comment: You probably meant $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_n^2 \color{red}{>}a_n^2$.

Comment: @MartinR: absolutely, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Revised and improved using OEIS

This is an extended comment.

The sequence starts as follows

$$\{a\}_{n=0}^{n=7} = 1,2,6,42,1806,3263442,10650056950806,113423713055421844361000442 ...$$

**Asymptotic behaviour**

You can also easily estimate the asymptotic behaviour of $a_n$.

Indeed, as $a_n$ becomes large very quickly you can write the recursion approximately as

$$a_{n+1}= a_{n}^2(1+\frac{1}{a_n}) \simeq a_{n}^2$$

The solution is

$$a_n \simeq e^{q \;2^n}$$

with some constant $q$.

$q$ can be calculated approximately numerically from the first few values of $a_n$ using $q = \lim_{n\to \infty} q_n $ where

$$ q_n = \frac{\log(a_n)}{2^n}$$

which gives the approximation sequence

$$\{q\}_{n=1}^{n=10} = \{0.346574,0.44794,0.467209,0.468679,0.468697,0.468697,0.468697,0.468697,0.468697,0.468697\}$$

Hence $q\simeq 0.468679$.

**Lookup of the series**

The series is listed as https://oeis.org/A007018

$$\text{A007018  a(n) = a(n-1)^2 + a(n-1), a(0)=1}$$

A confirmation of qour asymptotic behaviour and other interesting results can be found here, as e.g.

1) Donald Knuth showed that $a_n$ is the integer just a tiny bit below the real number $\theta^{2^n}-1/2$, where $\theta \simeq 1.597910218$ is the exponential of the rapidly convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \log(1+1/a_{n})/2^{n+1}$.

2) Formula (Benoit Cloitre) $a_n = \lfloor c^{2^n} \rfloor$ 
where $c = A077125 = 1.597910218031873178338070118157...$

The relation between $c$ and the $q$ obtaind above is simply $q = \log{c}$ which gives us more digits and shows that $q$ is a well-known constant.